# Reset a CSS counter with class

Tags: css

I have a problem when i want to reset a CSS counter with a class. I have understand that it's a scope problem, but when i try to change my code to do it works... it doesn't. I always initiate a new counter when i try to reset.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: num ;
}
.number {
  counter-increment: num;
}
.number::before {
  content: counters(num, ' - ');
}
.reset {
  counter-reset: num ;
}
```

```html
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number reset"> Reset</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
```

Can anybody help ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you would like to reset the counter only when `.reset` class applied, so just remove the `counter-reset: num;` in `body` will do :)

Comment: Seriously ? As easy as that ??? Thank you very much ! I tried so many things ! I tought that you always add to init the counter before using it.

Comment: You should indeed add `counter-reset: num;` to initialize it. But you can do that on `.number:nth-child(1)` instead of your body.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that for each level you get a new counter called num when you 'declare it' with some CSS. As body is a higher level than all the divs a new num is created when you 'declare it' in the divs level - you are not seeing the body level's one, you've created a new counter called num when you do a counter reset in the divs level.

So if you did:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: num ;
}
.number {
  counter-increment: num;
}
.number::before {
  content: counters(num, ' - ');
}
.reset {
  counter-reset: num ;
}
```

```html
<body class="number"><div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number reset"> Reset</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
<div class="number">-</div>
</body>
```

you'll see a new counter is created when you reset num in the div. This helps when you want to number sections and paragraphs in a text for example - you have several levels going at once.